# How to handle jersy rest api response in sprint rest api

Tags: spring, rest, jersey

I am invoking jersey rest api from sprint rest api. From jersey rest api the response is `javax.ws.rs.core.Response` object. How to decode/handle this object in sprint rest api end.

I am trying to handle with ResponseEntity in sprint rest but getting this error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error:
>   Unrecognized token 'success': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null'); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException:
>   Unrecognized token 'success': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null')
>    at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 15]

Thanks,
Hari.

Comment: You reference "sprint" but I know of no such REST API framework. Do you mean Spring? Your error message references Spring... If so, changing your tag as well as "sprint" references will help garner more attention.

Answer (score 0):

Your error message gives clue to what's failing:

`JSON parse error: Unrecognized token 'success': was expecting ('true', 'false' or 'null');`

The response your API is getting also includes a `success` key which might not be defined in your model, or however your code is handling that JSON parsing.

Comment: Response from jersey api is `Response.ok("success").build()`. Reading the response in sprint rest is `ResponseEntity<ResponseEntity> response`. The `success` reply is Unrecognized token